# C# - How to move objects when making another object visible

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagridview, size

I am creating a windows form application and i have checkbox to show "more options". So when this checkbox is checked i would like it to show the new parameters (which i have done) however i would also like everything else (datagridview) to then shift down. I have manually done this by adjusting the size of the datagridview, but then when i go full screen the size no longer anchors properly.

Is there a way in which i can make my datagridview move down but still hold the anchor property?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want shift it down or resize?

Comment: when i check the checkbox an additional text box appears over the datagridview (currently). What i want it to do is for the datagridview to shift down aswell. But i need it to keep its anchor properties so that when i adjust the size of the form on run time it all stays in the right place.

Comment: You can subtract  x from the dgv height and also add x to its top position. x being the space needed for the textbox and spacing. This will not affect the anchors.

Comment: Yep that has worked for me! Thank you. Pop that as an answer and i will give it the tick.

Comment: No, frankly I think this is too minor to warrant an answer and 'etrnal' entry in the SO archive..

Comment: I beg to differ for people who have not got many years experience with C# this could be very useful. But suit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done by calculating the height of the form and subtracting a certain amount off the height of the dgv and then moving the position of the dgv down enough to show the new fields.